# Data Manipulation in R: 'X' must be atomic

Tags: r, input, import-from-csv

I have imported a file with headings and numbers in multiple columns using the following command.
`irs_data <- read.csv(file="10incyallnoagi.csv")`

I would like to divide the values in 1 column by another and then determine the highest 3 values.

```
     salary_var <- c(irs_data[13]/irs_data[12])
     head(sort(new_var, decreasing=TRUE), 3)
```

I keep getting the constant error. As a beginner to **R**, what does it mean "x must be atomic" in this context.

```
Error in sort.int(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing, ...) : 
  'x' must be atomic
```

Comment: Hi, could you provide sample data so that contributors could assist?

Comment: The data can be found http://www.irs.gov/uac/SOI-Tax-Stats-County-Data, when you click on 2010. The file is 10incyallnoagi.csv.

Comment: Suggest to provide a snippet of data here.

Comment: http://snag.gy/YG9iF.jpg

Comment: Try `salary_var <- c(irs_data[[13]]/irs_data[[12]])`. It's not clear if `new_var` should actually be `salary_var` in your sort command.  If not, then we need more info.  The error is there because `new_var` is a list and lists are not atomic vectors.

Comment: You need to either do what @RichardScriven suggested or do `c(irs_data[,13]/irs_data[,12])` (but there's no need for the `c()` in either case). Do a `str(irs_data[13]))` vs a `str(irs_data[,13])` or `str(irs_data[[13]])` to see the difference in type/class.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that `salary_var` is a list containing a single-element. The call to `sort()` is then trying to sort a list, not an atomic element. You can see that `salary_var` is a list by running `str(salary_var)`. If you omit the `c()`, you'll instead end up with a data frame with a single column, which gives the same problem.

Two simple solutions:

To sort the values in the element of the list, use

```
head(sort(salary_var[[1]], decreasing=TRUE), 3)
```

where the [[1]] selects the first element of the list and sorts the values within it.

Alternatively, create `salary_var` explicitly as a numeric vector instead:

```
salary_var <- (irs_data[13]/irs_data[12])[[1]]
```

One note: in your post, you wrote `new_var` instead of `salary_var` in your call to `sort()` which may confuse other readers.

Answer (score 7):

you can use the **unlist()** to convert the list to a vector as the **sort()** 
function takes vector form for sorting.
so just use

```
head(sort(unlist(new_var), decreasing=TRUE), 3)
```