# Combing list into matrix: 'x' must be atomic

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I was trying to create a new dataset by populating it with a for loop, per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13442634/6110631). That is the **for loop** below:

```
sets = lapply(seq(-97, 99, by = 2), function(x) {
    nums[[1]] = x
    nums
})
stats = matrix(ncol=3, nrow=99)

for(i in 1:99) {
  stats[i] = c(
    sets[i[1]],
    mean(sets[i]),
    median(sets[i])
  )
}
```

Runtime error:

```
argument is not numeric or logical: returning NAError in
sort.int(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing, ...) : 
  'x' must be atomic
```

I don't even *have* a variable named x in the for loop, and I am *not* trying to sort anything. I jut want to calculate the three values and add them to a row in the dataframe. A [similar question was asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26247429/data-manipulation-in-r-x-must-be-atomic), but the poster *was* trying to sort something. What could be causing this error?

There was originally a , in `stats[i]` as in `stats[i,]`. I removed that but that did not fix the problem.

Comment: "*...and I am not trying to sort anything.*" Yes, you are trying to sort something. Calculating the median requires sorting.

Comment: @RHertel If I run median(sets[1]) for example outside the loop that works, so then why would it not work inside the loop?